# JQuery Datatbales using knockoutjs, getting selected row data

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, datatables

Can someone please help me in retrieving the selected row data from the Datatables using knockout js?

Currently I am using datatables and datatables select plugin, but question is how do I retrieve the data of the selected row and populate the span "" with the selected row -- Name column ?

So far, the grid renders and the selection works. If I do an on select of the row, I am not able to populate the view model, but I am not sure if it is the right way to do it.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.dataTable = {
      update: function(el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(el).DataTable(ko.toJS(valueAccessor()));
      }
    }



    var viewmodel = function() {

      var gridConf = {
        "Columns": "[{\"displayName\":\"Id\",\"field\":\"id\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":false},{\"displayName\":\"Name\",\"field\":\"name\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Position\",\"field\":\"position\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Office\",\"field\":\"office\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Extn\",\"field\":\"extn\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"StartDate\",\"field\":\"start_date\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true},{\"displayName\":\"Salary\",\"field\":\"salary\",\"width\":\"auto\",\"dataType\":\"string\",\"template\":\"\",\"visible\":true}]",
        "Data": "[{       \"id\": \"1\",       \"name\": \"Tiger Nixon\",       \"position\": \"System Architect\",       \"salary\": \"$320,800\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/04/25\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"5421\"     },     {       \"id\":\"2\",       \"name\": \"Garrett Winters\",       \"position\": \"Accountant\",       \"salary\": \"$170,750\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/07/25\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"8422\"     },     {       \"id\": \"3\",      \"name\": \"Ashton Cox\",       \"position\": \"Junior Technical Author\",       \"salary\": \"$86,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/01/12\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"1562\"     },     {       \"id\": \"4\",      \"name\": \"Cedric Kelly\",       \"position\": \"Senior Javascript Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$433,060\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/03/29\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"6224\"     },     {       \"id\": \"5\",      \"name\": \"Airi Satou\",       \"position\": \"Accountant\",       \"salary\": \"$162,700\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/11/28\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"5407\"     },     {       \"id\": \"6\",       \"name\": \"BrielleWilliamson\",       \"position\": \"Integration Specialist\",       \"salary\": \"$372,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/12/02\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"4804\"     },     {       \"id\": \"7\",       \"name\":\"Herrod Chandler\",       \"position\": \"Sales Assistant\",       \"salary\": \"$137,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/08/06\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"9608\"     },     {       \"id\": \"8\",       \"name\":\"Rhona Davidson\",       \"position\": \"Integration Specialist\",       \"salary\": \"$327,900\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/10/14\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"6200\"     },     {       \"id\": \"9\",       \"name\":\"Colleen Hurst\",       \"position\": \"Javascript Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$205,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/09/15\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"2360\"     },     {       \"id\": \"10\",      \"name\": \"Sonya Frost\",       \"position\": \"Software Engineer\",       \"salary\": \"$103,600\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/12/13\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"1667\"     },     {       \"id\": \"11\",       \"name\":\"Jena Gaines\",       \"position\": \"Office Manager\",       \"salary\": \"$90,560\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/12/19\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"3814\"     },     {       \"id\": \"12\",       \"name\": \"QuinnFlynn\",       \"position\": \"Support Lead\",       \"salary\": \"$342,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2013/03/03\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"9497\"     },     {       \"id\": \"13\",       \"name\": \"ChardeMarshall\",       \"position\": \"Regional Director\",       \"salary\": \"$470,600\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/10/16\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"6741\"     },     {       \"id\": \"14\",       \"name\": \"HaleyKennedy\",       \"position\": \"Senior Marketing Designer\",       \"salary\": \"$313,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/12/18\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"3597\"     },     {       \"id\": \"15\",       \"name\":\"TatyanaFitzpatrick\",       \"position\": \"Regional Director\",       \"salary\": \"$385,750\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/03/17\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"1965\"     },     {       \"id\": \"16\",       \"name\":\"Michael Silva\",       \"position\": \"Marketing Designer\",       \"salary\": \"$198,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/11/27\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"1581\"     },     {       \"id\": \"17\",       \"name\":\"PaulByrd\",       \"position\": \"Chief Financial Officer (CFO)\",       \"salary\": \"$725,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/06/09\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"3059\"     },     {       \"id\": \"18\",      \"name\": \"Gloria Little\",       \"position\": \"Systems Administrator\",       \"salary\": \"$237,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/04/10\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"1721\"     },     {       \"id\": \"19\",       \"name\":\"Bradley Greer\",       \"position\": \"Software Engineer\",       \"salary\": \"$132,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/10/13\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"2558\"     },     {       \"id\": \"20\",       \"name\": \"DaiRios\",       \"position\": \"Personnel Lead\",       \"salary\": \"$217,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/09/26\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"2290\"     },     {       \"id\": \"21\",       \"name\": \"JenetteCaldwell\",       \"position\": \"Development Lead\",       \"salary\": \"$345,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/09/03\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"1937\"     },     {       \"id\": \"22\",       \"name\": \"YuriBerry\",       \"position\": \"Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)\",       \"salary\": \"$675,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/06/25\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"6154\"     },     {       \"id\": \"23\",       \"name\":\"Caesar Vance\",       \"position\": \"Pre-Sales Support\",       \"salary\": \"$106,450\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/12/12\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"8330\"     },     {       \"id\": \"24\",       \"name\":\"Doris Wilder\",       \"position\": \"Sales Assistant\",       \"salary\": \"$85,600\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/09/20\",       \"office\": \"Sidney\",       \"extn\": \"3023\"     },     {       \"id\": \"25\",       \"name\": \"AngelicaRamos\",       \"position\": \"Chief Executive Officer (CEO)\",       \"salary\": \"$1,200,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/10/09\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"5797\"     },     {       \"id\": \"26\",       \"name\":\"Gavin Joyce\",       \"position\": \"Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$92,575\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/12/22\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"8822\"     },     {       \"id\": \"27\",       \"name\": \"JenniferChang\",       \"position\": \"Regional Director\",       \"salary\": \"$357,650\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/11/14\",       \"office\": \"Singapore\",       \"extn\": \"9239\"     },     {       \"id\": \"28\",       \"name\": \"BrendenWagner\",       \"position\": \"Software Engineer\",       \"salary\": \"$206,850\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/06/07\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"1314\"     },     {       \"id\": \"29\",       \"name\": \"FionaGreen\",       \"position\": \"Chief Operating Officer (COO)\",       \"salary\": \"$850,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/03/11\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"2947\"     },     {       \"id\": \"30\",       \"name\":\"Shou Itou\",       \"position\": \"Regional Marketing\",       \"salary\": \"$163,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/08/14\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"8899\"     },     {       \"id\": \"31\",       \"name\": \"MichelleHouse\",       \"position\": \"Integration Specialist\",       \"salary\": \"$95,400\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/06/02\",       \"office\": \"Sidney\",       \"extn\": \"2769\"     },     {       \"id\": \"32\",       \"name\": \"SukiBurks\",       \"position\": \"Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$114,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/10/22\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"6832\"     },     {       \"id\": \"33\",       \"name\": \"PrescottBartlett\",      \"position\": \"Technical Author\",       \"salary\": \"$145,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/05/07\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"3606\"     },     {       \"id\": \"34\",       \"name\": \"Gavin Cortez\",       \"position\":\"Team Leader\",       \"salary\": \"$235,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/10/26\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"2860\"     },     {       \"id\": \"35\",       \"name\": \"Martena Mccray\",       \"position\":\"Post-Sales support\",       \"salary\": \"$324,050\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/03/09\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"8240\"     },     {       \"id\": \"36\",       \"name\": \"Unity Butler\",       \"position\":\"Marketing Designer\",       \"salary\": \"$85,675\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/12/09\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"5384\"     },     {       \"id\": \"37\",       \"name\": \"Howard Hatfield\",      \"position\": \"Office Manager\",       \"salary\": \"$164,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/12/16\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"7031\"     },     {       \"id\": \"38\",       \"name\": \"Hope Fuentes\",      \"position\":\"Secretary\",       \"salary\": \"$109,850\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/02/12\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"6318\"     },     {       \"id\": \"39\",       \"name\": \"Vivian Harrell\",       \"position\":\"Financial Controller\",       \"salary\": \"$452,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/02/14\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"9422\"     },     {       \"id\": \"40\",       \"name\": \"Timothy Mooney\",      \"position\": \"Office Manager\",       \"salary\": \"$136,200\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/12/11\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"7580\"     },     {       \"id\": \"41\",       \"name\": \"Jackson Bradshaw\",       \"position\":\"Director\",       \"salary\": \"$645,750\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/09/26\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"1042\"     },     {       \"id\": \"42\",       \"name\": \"Olivia Liang\",       \"position\": \"SupportEngineer\",       \"salary\":\"$234,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/02/03\",       \"office\": \"Singapore\",       \"extn\": \"2120\"     },     {       \"id\": \"43\",       \"name\": \"Bruno Nash\",       \"position\": \"SoftwareEngineer\",       \"salary\": \"$163,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/05/03\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"6222\"     },     {       \"id\": \"44\",       \"name\": \"Sakura Yamamoto\",       \"position\": \"SupportEngineer\",       \"salary\": \"$139,575\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/08/19\",       \"office\": \"Tokyo\",       \"extn\": \"9383\"     },     {       \"id\": \"45\",       \"name\": \"Thor Walton\",       \"position\": \"Developer\",      \"salary\": \"$98,540\",       \"start_date\": \"2013/08/11\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"8327\"     },     {       \"id\": \"46\",       \"name\": \"Finn Camacho\",       \"position\": \"Support Engineer\",       \"salary\":\"$87,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/07/07\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"2927\"     },     {       \"id\": \"47\",       \"name\": \"Serge Baldwin\",       \"position\": \"Data Coordinator\",       \"salary\":\"$138,575\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/04/09\",       \"office\": \"Singapore\",       \"extn\": \"8352\"     },     {       \"id\": \"48\",       \"name\": \"Zenaida Frank\",       \"position\": \"Software Engineer\",       \"salary\":\"$125,250\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/01/04\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"7439\"     },     {       \"id\": \"49\",       \"name\": \"Zorita Serrano\",       \"position\": \"Software Engineer\",       \"salary\":\"$115,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2012/06/01\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"4389\"     },     {       \"id\": \"50\",       \"name\": \"Jennifer Acosta\",       \"position\": \"Junior JavascriptDeveloper\",       \"salary\": \"$75,650\",       \"start_date\": \"2013/02/01\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"3431\"     },     {       \"id\": \"51\",       \"name\": \"Cara Stevens\",       \"position\": \"SalesAssistant\",       \"salary\": \"$145,600\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/12/06\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"3990\"     },     {       \"id\": \"52\",       \"name\": \"Hermione Butler\",       \"position\": \"RegionalDirector\",       \"salary\": \"$356,250\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/03/21\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"1016\"     },     {       \"id\": \"53\",       \"name\": \"Lael Greer\",       \"position\": \"SystemsAdministrator\",       \"salary\": \"$103,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2009/02/27\",       \"office\": \"London\",       \"extn\": \"6733\"     },     {       \"id\": \"54\",       \"name\": \"Jonas Alexander\",       \"position\":\"Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$86,500\",       \"start_date\": \"2010/07/14\",       \"office\": \"San Francisco\",       \"extn\": \"8196\"     },     {       \"id\": \"55\",       \"name\": \"Shad Decker\",       \"position\":\"Regional Director\",       \"salary\": \"$183,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2008/11/13\",       \"office\": \"Edinburgh\",       \"extn\": \"6373\"     },     {       \"id\": \"56\",       \"name\": \"Michael Bruce\",       \"position\":\"Javascript Developer\",       \"salary\": \"$183,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/06/27\",       \"office\": \"Singapore\",       \"extn\": \"5384\"     },     {       \"id\": \"57\",       \"name\": \"Donna Snider\",      \"position\": \"Customer Support\",       \"salary\": \"$112,000\",       \"start_date\": \"2011/01/25\",       \"office\": \"New York\",       \"extn\": \"4226\"     }        ] "
      };
      var self = this;
      self.GridConfiguration = ko.observable();
      self.Columns = ko.observableArray([]);
      self.ColumnDefinitions = ko.observableArray([]);
      var selectColumn = {};
      selectColumn.targets = 0;
      selectColumn.data = null;
      selectColumn.orderable = false;
      selectColumn.className = 'select-checkbox';
      selectColumn.data = null;

      self.SelectedItem = {};
      self.SelectedItem = ko.observable();
      self.SelectedItem = $('.selected').data();

      self.ColumnDefinitions.push(selectColumn);
      self.Order = ko.observableArray([]);
      self.Order = [
        [1, 'asc']
      ];
      self.Select = ko.observable();
      self.Select = {
        style: 'single'
      };
      self.Columns.push({
        data: null,
        title: "",
        searchable: false,
        visible: true,
        orderable: false,
        defaultContent: ''
      });
      var columns = JSON.parse(gridConf.Columns);
      $.each(columns, function(key, value) {
        var my_item = {};
        my_item.data = value['field'];
        my_item.title = value['displayName'];
        my_item.visible = value['visible'];
        if (value['visible'] === false) {
          my_item.searchable = false;
        }
        self.Columns.push(my_item);
      });
      var gridData = JSON.parse(gridConf.Data);
      self.Data = ko.observableArray([]);
      self.Data = gridData;
    };

    var vm = new viewmodel()
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>


    <table data-bind="dataTable: { deferRender: true, scrollY: '200', scrollX: true,  paging: true, select:Select,  dom:'t,p', columns:Columns, columnDefs:ColumnDefinitions, data:Data, pagingType: 'full' }" class="stripe row-border order-column" cellspacing="0"
      width="100%">
    </table>
    <p>
      <span data-bind="selectedItem"></span>
    </p>
```

Comment: You can add an event listener in the `init` method of your custom binding: `$(el).DataTable().on("select", console.log)`. You'd probably get more help if you include the relevant code in this post instead of only linking to the jsfiddle. You can use the stack snippet to add an interactive example to your question.

Comment: @user3297291 -- Thank you for the advise. I will make sure to include any snippets inline going forward. I tried that on select in the update of the custom binding but how do I update the view model object and how do I use it in the view is where I am confused

Answer (score 0):

Assign any observable using () and not with `=`. If you use `=` it wont be observable anymore.

```
self.Select = ko.observable();
self.Select({style: 'single'});
```